# arreglar error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]?

Tags: condiciones

programa que evalua al alumno de acuerdo a su calificacion

- 1) Solicite al usuario una calificación (dato real) de una materia.
- 2) En el caso de que el dato introducido sea incorrecto, muestre por pantalla el mensaje:
- "ERROR: el valor debe ser >= 0 y <= 10.
- 3) Mientras que, la nota introducida sea incorrecta, repita los pasos 1 y 2, .
- 4) Muestre por pantalla:
- "EXCELENTE", en caso de que la nota sea mayor que 8.
- "APROBADO", en el caso de que la nota sea mayor o igual que 5.
- "REPROBADO", en el caso de que la nota sea menor que 5.
  */

  ## include

  ## include

  using namespace std;

  ```
  char calcular();
  void excelente();
  void aprobado();
  void reprobado();
  void error(int cal);
  int calificacion;

  void error(int cal)
  {
          cout << "entra";
          if (cal > 10){      
              cout << "ERROR: el valor debe ser >= 0 y <= 10." << endl;
      }
  }
  char calcular()
  {
          int opcion;

          cout << "Introduce tu calificacion: " << endl;
          cin  >> calificacion;
          if (calificacion == error){ //El mensaje me lo avisa aquí
              char error;
      }

  }
  ```

  int main()
  {
          cout << "Programa que evalua la materia con tu calificacion" << endl;
          calcular();
          return 0;
  }